# I want to add a forgotten password page to my login page, but I can't jump to it after I update the code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add a forgotten password page to my login page,

but I can't jump to it after I update the code.

The website error message：

- [vue-router] uncaught error during route navigation
- Uncaught (in promise) undefined
- Maximum call stack size exceeded

old code

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isLogin = localStorage.getItem("token") == "ImLogin";
  var role = localStorage.getItem('roles');
  if (isLogin) {
    if (to.matched.every(item => item.meta.indexOf(role) > -1)) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/tips');
    }
  } else {
    if (to.path !== "/login") next("/login");
    else next();
  }
});
```

new code

```
<v-btn
  class="font-weight-bold"
  style="color:#FF7D52"
  href
  @click.prevent="forgetPassword"
  text
  >forgetPassword
</v-btn>

forgetPassword() {
      this.$router.push("/forgetPassword");
    },
```

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const isLogin = localStorage.getItem("token") == "ImLogin";
  var role = localStorage.getItem('roles');
  if (isLogin) {
    if (to.matched.every(item => item.meta.indexOf(role) > -1)) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/tips');
    }
  } else {
    if (to.path === "/forgetPassword") {
      next("/forgetPassword");
    } else {
      if (to.path !== "/login") next("/login");
      else next();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: if the path is "forgetPassword" you go to "forgetPassword". Doesn't the create an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (to.path === "/forgetPassword") {
      next("/forgetPassword");
}
```

As Matt Ellen user suggested, this will create an infinite loop, since navigating to "/forgetpassword" triggers the router beforeEach hook again.

Simply `next();` should solve this problem.